# Apply jquery propieties on new element created after the page is loaded

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a problem with jquery and bootstraps modal. There's a page with a dynamic table and a modal that load remote content everytime is opened.

When I load the page for the first time everything works fine, but when I edit the table, to be more precise when I add or edit a row, the modal function stop working. In this cases the browser open directly the remote page, *read_properties.php*

This is how I call the modal, every row has a different id:

```
<a data-target="#id_target" href="read_properties.php?id=xx">
```

And this is the jQuery event that load remote content in to the modal (I found this solution here on Stackoverflow):

```
$("a[data-target=#id_target]").click(function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var target = $(this).attr("href");

  $("#id_target .modal-body").load(target, function() { 
   $("#id_target").modal("show"); 
  });
});
```

Thanks to all!

Comment: It seems like the `#id_target` ID is used more than once ?

Comment: @adeneo the `id="id_target"` is used only for the modal, instead i use `data-target="#id_target"` in every row of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple. I've edit the first line and use the .on event on the document body:

```
$(document.body).on('click', "a[data-target=#ads]", function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
  var target = $(this).attr("href");

  // load the url and show modal on success
  $("#ads .modal-body").load(target, function() { 
    $("#ads").modal("show"); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("a[data-target=#id_target]").live(function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var target = $(this).attr("href");

  $("#id_target .modal-body").load(target, function() { 
   $("#id_target").modal("show"); 
  });
});
```

Click will not be binded with dynamic html. So you need to use live listener.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. I try `live.(function(ev)..` and also `live.('click', function(ev)..`

Comment: @user3108269 - That's because live was deprecated some years ago, and is currently removed from jQuery, so no suprise there.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle??

Comment: Thanks, but i found the solution. I've edited my question with it