# Apply JS onto table, which is created after page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorttable.js

I have got an html page, where you can put text into a textarea, click a button and then it creates an html table. 
Problem is, that i am using a JS file to make my table sortable, but this JS file is not applied to tables that are created after the page itself is created. 
How can i call the JS file again after the button is clicked and the table created? Or is there any other way to apply the JS file to the new table?

My problem seems to be like this problem: 
[Apply jquery propieties on new element created after the page is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617477/apply-jquery-propieties-on-new-element-created-after-the-page-is-loaded)
But i can't use JQuery, is there any way without it?

Example for a created table:

```
<div id="artikelnr2">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="table.css">
<script src="java.js"></script>

        <div class="datagrid"><table class="sortable">
        <thead><tr><th>Nummer</th><th>Nummer</th><th>Bezeichnung</th><th>Bemerkungen</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
    <tr><td>897-251</td><td>00.702.07803.7</td><td>5G2</td><td>-</td></tr><tr><td>897-1051</td><td>00.702.0306.7</td><td>5G1</td><td>-</td></tr><tr><td>897-1651</td><td>00.702.0307.3</td><td>5G1U</td><td>-</td></tr><tr><td>897-341</td><td>00.702.0323.9</td><td>5G2.5</td><td>-</td></tr>
        </tbody>
        </table></div>
</div>
```

I am using sorttable.js from this page:
http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

JavaScript which is called after button is clicked (pastes the content of another page into an exisiting div container):

```
    function getOutput(url) {  
var file = selectedValue()+".csv";
var value = document.getElementById("artikelnr").value;
<!---Leerzeichen entfernen-->
value = myTrim(value); 
var url = url || "verarbeitung.php?eingabe="+value+"&eingabe2="+file ; 

  getRequest(
      url, // URL for the PHP file
       drawOutput,  // handle successful request
       drawError    // handle error
  );
  return false;
}

// handles drawing an error message
function drawError() {
    var container = document.getElementById('artikelnr2');
    container.innerHTML = 'Bummer: there was an error!';
}
// handles the response, adds the html
function drawOutput(responseText) {
    var container = document.getElementById('artikelnr2');
    container.innerHTML = responseText;
    tempResult = responseText; 
}
// helper function for cross-browser request object
function getRequest(url, success, error) {
    var req = false;
    try{
        // most browsers
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // IE
        try{
            req = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(e) {
            // try an older version
            try{
                req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch(e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!req) return false;
    if (typeof success != 'function') success = function () {};
    if (typeof error!= 'function') error = function () {};
    req.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(req.readyState == 4) {
            return req.status === 200 ? 
                success(req.responseText) : error(req.status);
        }
    }
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.send(null);
    return req;
}
```

Comment: Post the code that both sort table and how that is called, and the code that creates your new table.

Comment: [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded).

Comment: I meant your code/script, how you have implemented it, how your code calls the sort method, where/when it gets called and how it inserts the new table into the DOM.

Comment: I added my script, but it is quite long. Essentially it gets the text from the input box, sends it to another php page, which gets a result from the database and this result (which is a table) is displayed inside the div "artikelnr2"

Comment: @FynnKl I updated my answer showing how/where to call the `sorttable.makeSortable(newTableObject);` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is a suggestion as a major part of your code is not available.

In your existing code, where you create the new table, you need to add/run the following:

```
sorttable.makeSortable(newTableObject);
```

The `newTableObject` reference you either can get straight from your existing code or by calling `document.getElementById(idOfTheTableIJustAdded)` after your added the new table to the DOM.

Src: http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/

*Update after question edit:*

In this script function you should be able to do like this

```
function drawOutput(responseText) {
    var container = document.getElementById('artikelnr2');
    container.innerHTML = responseText;
    //tempResult = responseText;

    var newTableObject = container.querySelector(".sortable");
    sorttable.makeSortable(newTableObject);
}
```